# Fixing a sub menu from sliding right, to sliding down

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a menu that slides right on a website. I cannot find any css code that causes this to happen, so I am thinking it is in the javascript code instead. I am not very familiar with Javascript code and am unsure where to fix it. I need some advice. We want the menu to move downward instead, like in the top main menu. The website in question is: http://www.wvexecutive.com/

In the HTML and CSS code that I looked through, I noticed that the class .sf-js-enabled if disabled, disables the submenu and it doesn't work. This is the only thing that I have found that affects this animation.

I cannot find the style sheet for this code:

```
class="secondnav-menu sf-js-enabled sf-menu".
```

But here is the HTML:

```
<div id="categories_container">

<div id="categories">
<ul id="menu-main-menu"class="secondnav-menu sf-js-enabled sf-menu"><li id="menu-item-1004" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-1004"><a href="http://www.wvexecutive.com/">Home</a>
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
<li id="menu-item-25711" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-89 current_page_item menu-item-25711"><a href="http://www.wvexecutive.com/resources/" aria-current="page">Resources</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!-- #categories -->

</div>
```

And here is the css for this.

```
ul, menu, dir {
display: block;
list-style-type: disc;
margin-block-start: 1em;
margin-block-end: 1em;
margin-inline-start: 0px;
margin-inline-end: 0px;
padding-inline-start: 40px;

/* Categories */

#categories_shadow{
float:left;
background:url(images/categories_menu_shadow.png) no-repeat bottom     left;
height:61px;
}

#categories_container{
float:left;
width:100%;
}

#categories{
width:960px;
height:48px;
background: url(images/categories-bg.jpg) 0 0 repeat-x #601111;
/*border:1px solid #e1e1e1;*/
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
}

#categories .home_first_line{
border-left:1px solid #e1e1e1;
}

#categories .home_second_line{
border-left:1px solid #fff;
}

#categories ul{
float:left;
}

#categories ul li{
float:left;
list-style:none;
font-size:14px;
/*line-height:51px;*/
/*border-right:1px solid #560f0f;*/
}

#categories ul li ul li, #categories ul li ul li a {
border-right:none;
}

#categories ul li ul li a{
line-height:35px !important;
}

#categories ul li a{
text-decoration:none;
color:#fff;
display:block;
line-height:48px;
padding:0px 16px;
float:left;
/*border-right:1px solid #701414;*/
font-family: 'Antic Slab',Tahoma,serif;
}

#categories ul li a:hover{
background:#731414;
}

#categories .current-cat a, #categories .current-menu-item a, #categories     .current-menu-parent a, #categories .current_page_item a {
background:#731414;
}

#categories ul li ul li a:hover{
background:none;
color:#747474 !important;
}
```

Again, I want this menu to expand down, not to the side, on the right hand side. I didn't build this website and I am coming in behind another developer on this trying to navigate their code. I don't typically use javascript much myself. I use CSS.

Comment: try to remove #categories ul{float:left;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#categories ul li{
    position:relative
}
#categories ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Hi! While this code may solve OP's problem, it is encouraged on SO to explain why the code is a solution. Code only answers are discouraged on SO, as they do not help OP or future visitors in the long run. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. This is helpful, and I did add this code, but it doesn't seem to be fixing the issue. What was the reason for fixing the position to :relative?, and the other to absolute, etc?

Comment: Hi, I cleared my browser cache, and this indeed fix the issue. I very much appreciated the code! If you have a moment to write back or edit your answer to help me learn from this, why this worked, please do!